# Can not use autoplot with a tsibble

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, tsibble

I am following Rob Hyndman forecasting book and I can not use `autoplot` even in this simple example, extracted from the book:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tsibble)
y <- tsibble(Year = 2015:2019,
             Observation = c(123,39,78,52,110),
             index = Year)
autoplot(y)
```

I got the following error: `Error: Objects of type tbl_ts/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame not supported by autoplot`.
I have for sure that y is a `tsibble`:

```
y
# A tsibble: 5 x 2 [1Y]
   Year Observation
  <int>       <dbl>
1  2015         123
2  2016          39
3  2017          78
4  2018          52
5  2019         110
```

Comment: Try fablelite::autoplot(y)

ggplot does not support tsibble objects by default.
Loading fable or fablelite will effectively update how ggplot works to allow it to work with tsibble

Comment: I loaded `fable` and it works now.Couldn't find `fablelite`on CRAN.

Comment: fablelite is now called fabletools. Loading fable will automatically load fabletools.